# How to use Intel C/C++ compiler to compile CUDA8.0 , or nvcc?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, cuda, intel

I am using Intel c/c++ compiler(version 16.0), Cuda8.0 in Visual Studio, on Windows Platform.

Since Cuda8.0 Release Note says it now supports Intel c/c++ compiler.
[image]

However, I can't find out a way to set Intel compiler to be the specific host compiler though I change the compiler from VC++ to Intel in VS.

When I run my program, it comes up these error:

> nvcc fatal   : Compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH different than the one specified with -ccbin

I searched the solutions and almost all the answers happen in 2012 or 2013, seem to be outdated.

I am wondering how to use the supported Intel Compiler to run my cuda program? Thanks.

Comment: Intel compilers are only supported in Linux, not Windows